# Problem with dbUnit: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Statement

Tags: java, oracle, dbunit

I have a strange problem with dbUnit.
I use dbUnit 2.4.4, java 1.6, Spring (as db connection pool), Oracle 9 for my project with about 50 unit tests.
For some of them (when I run whole set of tests) I get such exception:

```
Closed Statement
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Closed Statement
[junit]     at com.myproj.DataAccess.Internal.BaseDAOTest.importToDb(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at com.myproj.DataAccess.Internal.MyDAOTest.testGetBuyClientOrders(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
```

importToDb method loads test data from XML file to database via dbUnit's DatabaseOperation.REFRESH.execute method and it is used in ALL tests.
If I run these tests with problems separately, there is no problems for them.
Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the code for importToDb? Ta.

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/mf19de0a

Answer (score 1):

I guess some of your tests close the database connection when they clean up. The next test tries to use this connection again for the import and fails.

Comment: I don't close connection explicitly in any of the test. All of them use use jdbcTemplate from Spring DAO library, so I don't need to operate with connections manually. Connections are closed in import function, but this function is the same for all tests.

Comment: Which datasource do you use? Is it the `SingleConnectionDataSource`?

Comment: Datasource description from my Spring config:

<bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true" singleton="true">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver.class}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
        <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="20"/>
    </bean>

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me, we had explicitly configured our connection cache to snipe long-lasting connections using two properties:

```
AbandonedConnectionTimeout
InactivityTimeout
```

[See Oracle's docs here regarding timeout properties](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10979/conncache.htm#sthref458)

It turned out that the query+processing time was just jumping the cusp of the two properties combined (AbandonedConnectionTimeout + InactivityTimeout < query time + resultset processing time).

To fix the issue, you can either raise your timeout limits or you can remove the timeout by setting them to 0 (the default)